# Determining continuous maps

Tags: general-topology

Hello I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\mathbb{R}$ have the Euclidean Topology (i.e., the usual topology). Let f and g be continuous maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the product $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly for, $h(x) = \min\{f(x),g(x)\}$.

My issue is finding continuous maps which I can compose to obtain $f(x)g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Note that the following maps are continuous:

1. $(f,g) \colon X \to \mathbf R^2$, where $(f,g)(x) = \bigl(f(x), g(x)\bigr)$ and $\mathbf R^2$ is equipped with the euclidian topology ($={}$ the product of $\mathbf R$'s euclidian topology with itself).
2. $\cdot\colon \mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R$, the multiplication of reals.
3. $\max\{\cdot,\cdot\}\colon \mathbf R^2 \to \mathbf R$.